# What can I do about wiggly tables at the coffee shop

Tags: california, safety

This morning I was at Starbucks Coffee Shop
sitting down having a hot coffee. When I got up to
go to get a napkin the table wiggled and I ended up burning my arm from hot coffee.

From what I see, there are "really" wiggly tables at this location. They try to place it at the edges of the store so not many people use it, but some of us end up using them specially on a crowded busy morning.

What can I do about this. I never got medical treatment at an ER, but I did lose a day of work due to this. I also want to do the community some good by taking action to prevent this from happening to any unsuspecting customers.

Comment: We can't offer legal advice on specific real-life situations here.  If you want to consider suing, contact a local lawyer.  If you just want them to change, a simple letter to the store or corporate management might be just as effective as legal action.

Answer (score 1):

You can hire an attorney to sue them for damages. The basis for that suit would be negligence, that is, they had a duty of care to you, but they failed to act in a reasonable manner to prevent the harm. A prominent question in such a case would be whether the damage was a foreseeable outcome (if not, there is no negligence), or one-time while foreseeable (if this is a repeat offense, the consequences to them of deliberately ignoring the problem could be worse). There is also the consideration of comparative liability, since you might have been able to avoid the situation by doing something else. In some states, any fault assignable to you means you lose, but in California they follow the pure comparative fault rule, where your portion of the liability is deducted from an award (but you can still collect something if it was 99% your fault).

[Here](https://www.eater.com/2017/5/19/15662790/starbucks-hot-coffee-lawsuit-florida-100k) is an incident involving Starbucks (lids) where the plaintiff won, [here](https://www.usatoday.com/story/money/2015/05/11/starbucks-lawsuit-hot-coffee-cop-police-officer/27148147/) is one where the plaintiff lost